# Как выглядит обращение к консоли и запрос динамической памяти на уровне машинных команд?

Tags: память, консоль, ассемблер

В книге А. Крупника по ассемблеру динамическая память вообще не рассматривается, но для работы с консолью он рекомендует пользоваться функцией WriteConsole. Судя по тому, что пишут на форумах, с динамической памятью тоже рекомендуют работать с помощью VirtualAlloc.

А что на аппаратном уровне делает VirtualAlloc? Какое-нибудь прерывание, или как-то узнаёт размер оперативки и просто выделяет указатель?

То же самое с консолью. Что происходит на аппаратном уровне, когда мы в консоль пишем текст? Особенно при выводе, от клавиатуры хотя бы прерывание есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Windows консоль - это, по сути, виртуальный текстовый экран, реализованный на базе обычного окна, ничем не отличающееся от других окон. Для вывода на нее не используются прерывания, а вызовы функций WinAPI. Скорее всего `WriteConsole` где-то внутри вызывает `DrawText`, а дальше уже ОС берет шрифт и им рисует на экране через драйвер. Драйвер уже напрямую обращается к видеокарте.

При вводе аналогично не используются прерывания, а просто просматриваются сообщения окна консоли, выбираются нажатия на символьные клавиши, и коды соответствующих символов записываются в буфер, откуда уже "консольные" функции могут забирать их в виде текста.

С памятью немножко другая ситуация. Допустим, ОС имеет доступ ко всей физической памяти. При запуске большая часть памяти не принадлежит никакому приложению. По мере запуска программ ОС выделяет им память и где-то у себя отмечает, что вот этот кусочек памяти принадлежит этой программе. При освобождении памяти и закрытии программ память отмечается как незанятая. Никакой особой магии тут нет, просто [менеджер памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CC%E5%ED%E5%E4%E6%E5%F0_%EF%E0%EC%FF%F2%E8).

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у видеокарты свои машинные команды, которые генерирует драйвер? А как выглядит "напрямую общается"? Запись их в диапазон адресов, на которые отображается видеокарта? А что тогда между адресами и самим устройством?

Comment: @Modus, имеет смысл посмотреть, как это делается в какой-нибудь opensource операционной системе, например ReactOS (достаточно близко к Windows). Я прикладник, а не системщик, не в курсе таких низкоуровневых деталей.

Comment: @Modus, сильно зависит от производителя и модели видеокарты. Но в любом случае всё сводится к пересылке запросов по PCI-шине (разъём такой) через южный мост (раньше это была отдельная микросхема, как сейчас — не знаю). Даже прямой доступ к памяти (DMA) со стороны видеокарты сводится к последовательной вычитке небольших блоков серией PCI-запросов (то есть никаких отдельных контактов на колодке для этого не предусмотрено).